Microsoft Search Graph API returning missing results when using the 'from' property
Summary:  We are facing an issue where when using Microsoft Graph Search API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query); when using the 'from' property to skip items to get to a page; sometimes there are missing results from that page (e.g. 8 results even if 'size' is set to 10) or none at all (e.g. no hits resulting in a blank page).
We have found this on several different tenants we tested on and with different browser (Chrome, Edge). It can be replicated using Microsoft Graph Epxlorer with a simplified query. This seems to happen quite frequently and is resulting in a bad end user experience.
The queries are using only the basic listItem entitype. This is the example of the simplified query ->

We are trying to follow the documentation as explained here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/searchrequest?view=graph-rest-1.0
Tests we tried
Here are a list of different tests by simply updating the 'from' property in the query's payload shown above.
E.g. When From = 0 we have 10 hits as expected.

And showing there are 20,837 results.
Then we go up to page 10 by changing the from property to 90 ->

And here also showing the 10 results correctly. The result count seems to still make sense, though it changed without changing the query.
Then another example to the next page 11 by changing the from property to 100 ->

And suddenly we have no results. Also the total count changed by a lot, though still a lot higher than 120 results so we expect to see results in any case. Thus suddenly this page has 10 missed results.
The behavior seem to happen at random pages, sometimes resulting in empty pages and sometimes missing results in certain pages e.g. showing 7 from the 10 results even though should be size = 10.
Is there a workaround for this or a way to ensure that results are always returned properly even if it results in a performance cost?

Adding further details to answer comment below with further tests
I ran a test as follows with size always 10

Note that 40,50,60,70,80,110 and 120 all have missing hits.
Then after about 30 minutes I tried query with from 110 and got 0 hits. This is same query were previously when from was 160 we also had results, so results should be available.

I have the same issue and have asked the Microsoft community for help and got the following answer:
"There is some issue in sharepoint backend, Users' SharePoint Online content search results may be missing. You could refer to the report in Service health
https://admin.microsoft.com/adminportal/home?#/servicehealth/:/alerts/SP709902
The repair job to ensure content search results populate as expected is around 40 percent to completion. We estimate that this process should take approximately two weeks to complete and fully resolve this issue for all affected users."

Thanks for sharing the info. This seems like it can be very related and the bug has been opened since January. Maybe that explains why we have been seeing this for a while now. Hopefully will be resolved once this is closed. Then we can only wait and see for now.

The ticket seem to have been closed this morning but the issue is still happening. Is there a way to force a refresh of the MS search index, or do we wait a week or two?

You cannot trust the total property. The best you can do is that when you have moreResultsAvailable=true is to up the start count with what you previously used as size and keep on paging until there are no more results.
If you want to list all results and depending on the max count try to follow the guidance from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/pagination-for-large-result-sets which would also apply to the Graph API.
The API has been tuned to work towards user facing scenarios, thus the number of results above 500 is typically not useful to scroll thru for a person.
The max page size is documented to be 500, so if you need a lot of items you can request this from the start.

Thanks. We do not want to list all results, but to allow to jump from page 1 to 5 or 15 with size of just 10 as per the documentation here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#page-search-results. Sometimes it is happening where for example page 3 has 10 results as expected, then page 5 has 0 results, but then page 10 is fine.
I understand that the total count is not accurate, but that is not our main concern. In my test there are 1000s of expected result so should have results for page 5 with size 10.

If you page one by one page, do you get the right size per page? And are there then 10 pages as an example? Just because total says 20000 does not mean there is. It could be only 100.

I ran a test as follows with size always 10. Results shown in this format -> From property in query || Number of returned Hits in result  ---> 0||10; 10||10; 20||10; 30||10; 40||9; 50||9; 60||9; 70||9; 80||9; 90||10; 100||10; 110||7; 120||130||9; 140||10; 150||10; 160||10. Note how with from 40,50,60,70,80, 110 and 120 all have missing results. Then after about 30 minutes I tried query with from 110 again and this time I got 0 hits. This is same query and environment where previously with from = 160 we had results, so results should be available.

P.S. - I updated original post above with this info for better formatting. Thanks.

I would then log this as an API issue with the Graph team.
